# Rotating the column name for a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to make nicely formatted tables from pandas. Some of my column names are far too long. The cells for these columns are large cause the whole table to be a mess.

In my example, is it possible to rotate the column names as they are displayed?

```
data = [{'Way too long of a column to be reasonable':4,'Four?':4},
        {'Way too long of a column to be reasonable':5,'Four?':5}]
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: I would like to rotate the names of the columns as displayed here.]

Comment: could you please added tag `jupyter notebook`

Comment: Obviously this depends on your situation, but maybe it makes sense to just shorten/improve the column names?  But for a workaround, you could consider converting to a "fake" multi-index.  E.g. if column name is "david s pumpkins" you could have "david s" as the top level and "pumpkins" as the second level.  Obviously that's not what multi-indexes are for, but I think it would basically do what you want.

Comment: @JohnE, Thanks for the suggestion. A text wrap is what @Wen had suggested which is deleted but was: `df.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector="th",props=[('max-width', '50px')])])`

It's a good work-around that works for phrases, like in my example. I also have long words though. I'm still curious to see if rotation is possible! I'm no CSS selector expert, but I thought this should work but doesn't: `dfoo.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector="th",props=[('text-orientation', 'upright')])])`

Comment: I just re-read the doc page (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/style.html) which states that _'You can only style the values, not the index or columns'_, but the doc shows columns and indices being formatted. Maybe this is is just starting to be addressed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like:

```
data = [{'Way too long of a column to be reasonable':4,'Four?':4},
        {'Way too long of a column to be reasonable':5,'Four?':5}]
dfoo = pd.DataFrame(data)
dfoo.style.set_table_styles(
    [dict(selector="th",props=[('max-width', '80px')]),
        dict(selector="th.col_heading",
                 props=[("writing-mode", "vertical-rl"), 
                        ('transform', 'rotateZ(-90deg)'),
                        ])]
)
```

is probably close to what you want:

[image]

[see result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGNXj.png)

Comment: Changing my accepted answer. This does the task using only the Pandas library and will display in a JupyterLab. Well done!

Comment: I found that (in Firefox) the `rotateZ(-90deg)` argument caused the headings to *rotate back* so they were horizontal again.  I got a much nicer layout with `('vertical-align', 'text-top'), ('transform', 'rotateZ(180deg)')`, which aligned the text along the first row of the table.

Comment: Following @Nate's comment the setting which rotated the column names correctly was `props=[('vertical-align', 'text-top'), ('transform', 'rotateZ(-90deg)')]`

Answer (score 4):

I placed @Bobain's nice answer into a function so I can re-use it throughout a notebook.

```
def format_vertical_headers(df):
    """Display a dataframe with vertical column headers"""
    styles = [dict(selector="th", props=[('width', '40px')]),
              dict(selector="th.col_heading",
                   props=[("writing-mode", "vertical-rl"),
                          ('transform', 'rotateZ(180deg)'), 
                          ('height', '290px'),
                          ('vertical-align', 'top')])]
    return (df.fillna('').style.set_table_styles(styles))

format_vertical_headers(pandas.DataFrame(data))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not getting the same layout - text is upside down horizontal and wrapped. . Not enough space to explain the limited progress I have made with trying different parameters.  Maybe add another comment to explain them? print(pd.__version__) says my pandas version is 1.2,1 and jupyter version is jupyter core     : 4.7.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.4.3
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.26.0
ipykernel        : 6.1.0
jupyter client   : 6.1.12
jupyter lab      : 3.1.6
nbconvert        : 6.1.0
ipywidgets       : not installed
nbformat         : 5.1.3
traitlets        : 5.0.5

Comment: Best mod I've found is below but still not vertical: 

def format_vertical_headers(df):
    """Display a dataframe with vertical column headers"""
    styles = [dict(selector="th", props=[('width', '40px')]),
              dict(selector="th.col_heading",
                   props=[("writing-mode", "vertical-rl"),
                          ('transform', 'rotateZ(180deg)'),
                          ('height', '290px'),
                          ('vertical-align', 'top')])]
    return (df.fillna('').style.set_table_styles(styles))

format_vertical_headers(pd.DataFrame(data))

Comment: @Bill please ask a new question and provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [pybloqs source code](https://github.com/manahl/PyBloqs/blob/master/pybloqs/block/table_formatters.py) for the accepted answer's solution, I was able to find out how to rotate the columns without installing pybloqs.  Note that this also rotates the index, but I have added code to remove those.

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display

data = [{'Way too long of a column to be reasonable':4,'Four?':4},
        {'Way too long of a column to be reasonable':5,'Four?':5}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

styles = [
    dict(selector="th", props=[("font-size", "125%"),
                               ("text-align", "center"),
                              ("transform", "translate(0%,-30%) rotate(-5deg)")
                              ]),
    dict(selector=".row_heading, .blank", props= [('display', 'none;')])
]

html = df.style.set_table_styles(styles).render()
display(HTML(html))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the Python library 'pybloqs' (http://pybloqs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it is possible to rotate the column names as well as add a padding to the top. The only downside (as the documentation mentions) is that the top-padding does not work inline with Jupyter. The table must be exported.

```
import pandas as pd
from pybloqs import Block
import pybloqs.block.table_formatters as tf
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

data = [{'Way too long of a column to be reasonable':4,'Four?':4},
        {'Way too long of a column to be reasonable':5,'Four?':5}]
dfoo =pd.DataFrame(data)

fmt_header = tf.FmtHeader(fixed_width='5cm',index_width='10%', 
                          top_padding='10cm', rotate_deg=60)
table_block = Block(dfoo, formatters=[fmt_header])

display(HTML(table_block.render_html()))
table_block.save('Table.html')
```

[image: Table in HTML with rotated column names]

Answer (score 1):

I can get it so that the text is completely turned around 90 degrees, but can't figure out how to use `text-orientation: upright` as it just makes the text invisible :( You were missing the `writing-mode` property that has to be set for `text-orientation` to have any effect. Also, I made it only apply to column headings by modifying the selector a little.

`dfoo.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector="th.col_heading",props=[("writing-mode", "vertical-lr"),('text-orientation', 'upright')])])`

Hopefully this gets you a little closer to your goal!

Comment: This is definitely getting warmer! All of the individual letters are rotated at least