# python corr rotating column names correlation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, correlation

I have below code from [this - 2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432629/plot-correlation-matrix-using-pandas)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rs = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(rs.rand(10, 10))
corr = df.corr()
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm')
```

it prints this. How can i rotate column names by 90 degrees in the below image?

[image]

#### Update 1

I updated code as below but it didnt help

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
rs = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(rs.rand(10, 10))
corr = df.corr()
corr.style.set_table_styles(
    [dict(selector="th",props=[('max-width', '80px')]),
        dict(selector="corr.col_heading",
                 props=[("writing-mode", "vertical-rl"), 
                        ('transform', 'rotateZ(-90deg)'),
                        ])])
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm')
```

Comment: Hi, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53318677/11246056

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotating the column name for a Panda DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715736/rotating-the-column-name-for-a-panda-dataframe)

Comment: @Laurent not sure if that will help as my output is not a dataframe

Comment: not helping :( - i have updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rs = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(rs.rand(10, 10))

df.corr().style.background_gradient(cmap="coolwarm").set_table_styles(
    [
        dict(
            selector="th.col_heading",
            props=[
                ("writing-mode", "vertical-rl"),
                ("transform", "rotateZ(180deg)"),
                ("height", "5px"),
            ],
        ),
    ]
)
```

Which outputs:

[image]